# Middle element gets all space between elements

Tags: css

I would like to style list as following:
[image]

I tried using following HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="label">a</span>
    <span class="middle-separator"></span>
    <span class="data">aaa</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I couldn't figure out how with CSS is possible to have dynamic size on the middle element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One posibility is to use flex to make middle separator to grow

apply this style:

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.middle-separator {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: that border bottom is not too nice... that should be a background and repeat-x